# Dot complexity for sparse matrix and vector for different formats

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to understand why time for dot product of sparse matrix and dense vector is increasing: `csr` is fastest, then `csc`, `coo`, `lil` and `dok` (slowest). In other words I measure time of this programm for diferrent `fmt`:

```
A = scipy.sparse.random(1000, 1000, format=fmt)
b = np.random.randn(1000, 1)
res = %timeit -o A * b
```

I want to find source code of scipy for function of dot. It is easy for `csr`, `coo` and `csc` ([csr_matvec](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2526df72e5d4ca8bad6e2f4b3cbdfbc33e805865/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h), [coo_matvec](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2526df72e5d4ca8bad6e2f4b3cbdfbc33e805865/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/coo.h) and csc_matvec - it should be third link, if I have had 10 reputaion =) ). But I cannot find such function for `lil` and `dok`. Could anybody answer how I can find it?

Comment: The matrix product is defined for the `csr` (and `csc`) format.  The other formats are first converted to `csr`, so the calculation times will include that conversion time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [298]: M=sparse.coo_matrix(np.eye(3))
```

Products for a `lil` format are performed by first converting to `csr`:

```
In [299]: Ml=M.tolil()
In [300]: Ml._mul_vector??
Signature: Ml._mul_vector(other)
Source:   
    def _mul_vector(self, other):
        return self.tocsr()._mul_vector(other)
File:      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py
Type:      method
```

`dok` does it's own.  A `dok` is a subclass of `dict`.

```
In [303]: Md=M.todok()
In [304]: Md._mul_vector??
Signature: Md._mul_vector(other)
Source:   
    def _mul_vector(self, other):
        # matrix * vector
        result = np.zeros(self.shape[0], dtype=upcast(self.dtype,other.dtype))
        for (i,j),v in iteritems(self):
            result[i] += v * other[j]
        return result
File:      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/dok.py
```

but for multiplication with another sparse matrix, it does the `csr` conversion.

```
In [305]: Md._mul_sparse_matrix??
Signature: Md._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
Source:   
    def _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other):
        return self.tocsr()._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
File:      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py
```

Note that this last code is in `base.py`.  This is where generic sparse code resides.  If the format doesn't define its own method, it uses the base version.

```
In [306]: Md.__class__.__mro__
Out[306]: 
(scipy.sparse.dok.dok_matrix,
 scipy.sparse.base.spmatrix,
 scipy.sparse.sputils.IndexMixin,
 dict,
 object)
```

`coo` also converts to `csr` for the full matrix product.